# Video view too small (Android)

Tags: android

I have a video view to stream a video, it works fine but the size of the video is too small, I tried streaming in the API demos and the size of the same video is normal. What have I done wrong? Here is some code:

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:paddingLeft="2px" 
        android:paddingRight="2px"
        android:paddingTop="2px" 
        android:paddingBottom="2px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <VideoView 
            android:id="@+id/VideoView"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Main.java**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.video);

                VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
                MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
                mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.free-3gp-video.com/download.php?do-beer-not-drugs.3gp");
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                videoView.start();
}
```

Comment: I have this problem. Do you found solution?

Answer (score 4):

No need of code to play video in full screen mode

#### Apply the following layout format over the xml containing the videoview it will for sure will play the video in full screen mode. as it is running mine :) Hope it helps

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```